# Perform a SQL JOIN on Django models that are not related?

Tags: python, django, orm

I have 2 Models, User (django.contrib.auth.models.User) and a model named Log.  Both contain an "email" field.  Log does not have a ForeignKey pointing to the User model.  I'm trying to figure out how I can perform a JOIN on these two tables using the email field as the commonality.

There are basically 2 queries I want to be able to perform.  A basic join for filtering

```
#Get all the User objects that have related Log objects with the level parameter set to 3.
User.objects.filter(log__level=3)
```

I'd also like to do some aggregates.

```
User.objects.all().anotate(Count('log'))
```

Of course, it would be nice to be able to do the reverse as well.

```
log = Log.objects.get(pk=3)
log.user...
```

Is there a way to do this with the ORM?  Maybe something I can add to the model's Meta class to "activate" the relation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an extra method onto the User class, using MonkeyPatching/DuckPunching:

```
def logs(user):
    return Log.objects.filter(email=user.email)

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.logs = property(logs)
```

Now, you can query a User, and ask for the logs attached (for instance, in a view):

```
user = request.user
logs = user.logs
```

This type of process is common in the Ruby world, but seems to be frowned upon in Python.

*(I came across the DuckPunching term the other day. It is based on Duck Typing, where we don't care what class something is: if it quacks like a duck, it is a duck as far as we are concerned. If it doesn't quack when you punch it, keep punching until it quacks).*

Comment: This, combined with Annotate, should cover both of your use cases, I think.

Comment: So to "Get all the User objects that have related Log objects with the level parameter set to 3" you should call logs function for every user. Seems like a lot of queries. Extra allows to perform this in one query.

Answer (score 2):

why not use [extra()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none)?

example (untested):

```
User.objects.extra(
    select={
        'log_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myapp_log WHERE myapp_log.email = auth_user.email'
    },
)
```

for the `User.objects.filter(log__level=3)` portion here is the equivalent with extra (untested):

```
User.objects.extra(
    select={
        'log_level_3_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myapp_log WHERE (myapp_log.email = auth_user.email) AND (myapp_log.level=3)'
    },
).filter(log_level_3_count__gt=0)
```

Comment: This works for the anotate use case. But not for the other user case I mentioned.  I'm trying to find a way to do it with a single Query from within the ORM (I'd rather not resort to raw SQL if possible).

Comment: Why limit to one query? See if doing it with separate queries is fast enough for now, and when it isn't then look at optimising.

Comment: you can filter based on the things you add with extra()

Answer (score 0):

Do the Log.email values always correspond to a User?  If so, how about just adding a ForeignKey(User) to the Log object?

```
class Log(models.Model):
    # ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

With the FK to User, it becomes fairly straight forward to find what you want:

```
User.objects.filter(log__level=3)
User.objects.all().anotate(Count('log'))

user.log_set.all()
user.log_set.count()

log.user
```

If the Log.email value does not have to belong to a user you can try adding a method to a [model manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/).

```
class LogManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return super(LobManager, self).get_query_set().filter(email=user.email)

class Log(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = LogManager()
```

And then use it like this:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
logs_for_user = Log.objects.for_user(user)
```

Comment: Log is actually part of a 3rd part app.  So adding a new field is not ideal.